# Checking if the input field is completed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, hook, styling

**how can I check if the input fields are completed when clicking the Submit button? I'd like to alert if one of the inputs isn't completed or, if they all are completed - display a component in the App.vue file. But my validation checking seems not to be working.

```js
<template>
  <button class="btn" @click="submit">Submit</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    submit() {
      if (
        !this.firstName &&
        !this.lastName &&
        !this.paymentAmount &&
        !this.accountNumber
      ) {
        this.$emit("final");
      } else {
        alert("please fill the required fields");
      }
    },
  },
  inject: ["firstName", "lastName", "paymentAmount", "accountNumber"],
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.btn {
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
</style>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-jasper-teh1im?file=/src/components/Button.vue**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to wrap your inputs inside a `<form>` element (lowercased!) to get native form validation.

```html
// Form.vue
<template>
  <form ref="myForm">
    <KeepAlive>
      <component :is="currentStep" @previous="previousStep" @next="nextStep" />
    </KeepAlive>
  </form>
</template>
```

You can also check the validity programatically by using `this.$refs.myForm. checkValidity()`.